# How i can scanning BLE in fragment on Android Studio

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have Bluetooth 4.0 BLE installed on my Arduino Atmega 2560, and i need to use app Android (I made in Android Studio) to scanning the dispositive and send data, as "1" to on led and "0" to off led, but, this code needed stay on fragment. This is source code of Class Fragment of APP:

The method to scanning a device do not work, a lot of errors...

Example: "Cannot resolve leScanCallback"

Exist a problem to use BLE in a fragment layout? I need only send and future receive the data from communication in between Android Device and Arduino Device.

I added the method private LeDeviceListAdapter leDeviceListAdapter;
But still error of Cannot Resolve return for me, now, to "LeDeviceListAdapter";

````java
    public class ManejoFragment extends Fragment {
    private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private ManejoViewModel manejoViewModel;
    private Button btnLigarDesligar;
    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;


    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        manejoViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ManejoViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tela_manejo, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_tools);
        manejoViewModel.getText().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) { // Puxa o texto definido na classe anterior e mostra na tela de Manejo
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });

        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

        if(!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);

        }
        btnLigarDesligar = (Button)root.findViewById(R.id.botaoLigarDesligar);
        btnLigarDesligar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        return root;
    }


    } ```

``` java
 public class DeviceScanActivity extends ListActivity {

    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private boolean mScanning;
    private Handler handler;

    // Stops scanning after 10 seconds.
    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;

    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mScanning = false;
                    bluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(leScanCallback);
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);

            mScanning = true;
            bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(leScanCallback);
        } else {
            mScanning = false;
            bluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(leScanCallback);
        }

    }

}```

private LeDeviceListAdapter leDeviceListAdapter;

    // Device scan callback.
    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback leScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,
                                     byte[] scanRecord) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            leDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                            leDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
}
````

Answer (score 0):

Simple Android BLE Scanner

- AndroidManifest.xml
- TestActivity.kt (Kotlin)
- test_layout.xml

AndroidManifest should contain :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

TestActivity.kt:

```
import android.Manifest
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager
import android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.test_layout.*


class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var btScanner: BluetoothLeScanner? = null
    private var btManager: BluetoothManager? = null
    private var btAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? = null
    private var isScanning = false

    private val REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1
    private val PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 1

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.test_layout)

        btManager = getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as? BluetoothManager
        btAdapter = btManager?.adapter
        btScanner = btAdapter?.bluetoothLeScanner

        if (btAdapter != null && !btAdapter!!.isEnabled) {
            val enableIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)
        }

        // Make sure we have access coarse location enabled, if not, prompt the user to enable it
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            val builder =
                AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            builder.setTitle("This app needs location access")
            builder.setMessage("Please grant location access so this app can detect peripherals.")
            builder.setPositiveButton("ok", null)
            builder.setOnDismissListener {
                requestPermissions(
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION),
                    PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION
                )
            }
            builder.show()
        }

        button.setOnClickListener {
            if (isScanning) {
                stopScanning()
            } else {
                startScanning()
            }
        }

    }

    // Device scan callback.
    private val leScanCallback: ScanCallback = object : ScanCallback() {
        override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult) {
            editText.append("Device Name: " + result.device?.name?.toString() + " rssi: " + result.rssi.toString() + "\n")

        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {

        when (requestCode) {
            PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION -> {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    println("coarse location permission granted")
                } else {
                    val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    builder.setTitle("Functionality limited")
                    builder.setMessage("Since location access has not been granted, this app will not be able to discover beacons when in the background.")
                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                    builder.show()
                }
                return
            }
        }
    }

    private fun startScanning() {
        println("start scanning")
        isScanning = true
        AsyncTask.execute { btScanner?.startScan(leScanCallback) }
    }

    private fun stopScanning() {
        println("stopping scanning")
        isScanning = false
        AsyncTask.execute { btScanner?.stopScan(leScanCallback) }
    }

}
```

test_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Start/Stop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```